# Tweet photo with twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

Is it possible to tweet a photo with the twitter gem in rails?

I know you can do regular text, like below

Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")

But how do I include an image url that gets uploaded?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the Twitter gem by sferik, I think this method here might be helpful. http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/API/Tweets#update_with_media-instance_method
Basically you want to use the update_with_media method. More information from Twitter is on their site https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media. Hope that helps!

Comment: The first link is dead. This is a actuall document of `update_with_media` now.  http://rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/twitter/Twitter/Client:update_with_media

Comment: The most recent link for this doc is: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Update.md